# Corrupted State Exception types other than AccessViolationException

Tags: .net, exception, clr, corrupted-state-exception

What Corrupted State Exception types, other than `AccessViolationException` are possible?

In particular, is it safe to assume that none of `OutOfMemoryException`, `ThreadAbortedException`, `SEHException`, `RuntimeWrappedException`, etc. require the use of `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute` to be caught, say, by a `catch (Exception)` clause?

I'm interested even in examples, guesses, approximations, of what exception types are sometimes or always treated by the CLR as a CSE.  Existing web resources give the appearance that CSE is a near-synonym for `AccessViolationException`, but I suspect that this might be too inaccurate even for my modest needs.

I need to know, whenever I notice a `catch (OutOfMemoryException)` (or another construct explicitly dealing with other low level exceptions) in ancient code I'm peripherally responsible for, whether the exception handling code could have been made unreachable, or is at risk of becoming unreachable, by migration to .NET 4.

So far my best bet was to scan Microsoft documentation of the exception type for a mention of `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute`, but I wonder whether this detail of behavior is even supposed to be fully compatible across all .NET 4 versions, and/or thoroughly documented for every managed exception type affected by the CLR change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there even is a finite set of exceptions (regardless of CLR versions, but in general).

At least native code (or the CLR itself) could raise any exception, designating it as corrupting state, if you look at [this](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/cb87aaebb321edd9ed74786305953314acfefda3/src/vm/excep.h#L265) CLR function.

```
   // Signature simplified for purposes of that answer, check link above for actual signature.
   void RealCOMPlusThrow(OBJECTREF throwable, CorruptionSeverity severity = NotCorrupting);
```

That function (i.e. the macro `COMPlusThrow` that wraps it) is called in multiple places in the (Core) CLR.

The function `IsProcessCorruptedStateException` function seems to be ultimately used to determine if an exception is considered state corrupting. This function has two "overloads".

[One](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/cb22707acb620e93a30254ded3048912a9ccb26f/src/utilcode/util.cpp#L2998) is rather helpful, because it lists the following exception codes:

```
    STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
    STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW
    EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION
    EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR
    EXCEPTION_INVALID_DISPOSITION
    EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE_EXCEPTION
    EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION
    STATUS_UNWIND_CONSOLIDATE
```

At least paritially they map to .NET exception objects.

However, the [other one](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/cb87aaebb321edd9ed74786305953314acfefda3/src/vm/excep.cpp#L11321) "simply" [checks](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/cb87aaebb321edd9ed74786305953314acfefda3/src/vm/excep.cpp#L11359) if the exception object (native, not managed) has been marked was state corrupting.

Now, I'm far far far away from being an expert with the CLR's code, so YMMV.

One can surely spend hours in the CLR code to figure out how corrupted state handling works and what consequences that has for handling those in C# code.
But depending on what you are *really* trying to achieve by your question that
might lead to some serious yack shaving. ;-)

Comment: This was extremely helpful.  I learned from you that "corrupted process state" was a pre-existing concept orthogonal to the SEH (or managed) exception type.  I received a much better approximation of the type of conditions when it hits, and (from noticing CorruptionSeverity.ReuseForReraise in the CLR code), that its travel within the process across Reflection and AD boundaries is also optional, with TargetInvocationException another example of a potential CSE, and I'll post a particularly valuable lesson about OutOfMemoryException as a separate Q+A pair.

Comment: Separate Q+A pair [created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652300/is-handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute-needed-for-catching-outofmemor) as promised.